# Should we base heavily on local jwt token expiry date to authenticate user

Tags: angular, jwt, angular2-jwt

I am learning angular2 by following some tutorials on the web. When making a login page using jwt token, lots of examples approach like:
- when user inputs email and password, submit event will call authentication api
- successed authentication will return a token with expiry date in payload. This token is stored in localstorage
- restricted routes navigation will check authenticated user by getItem from localstorage, check token existence and expiry date

My problem is:
I can easily go to jwt.io with the token in localstorage, change the expiry number to something else later, copy the new generated token and manually paste back to localstorage item

My thought:
Call api tokenValidation before any route navigation, bit it seems will introduce lots of server calls

Appriciate your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The whole point of JWT tokens is that they are cryptographically signed, using a key that only the server knows. So if you try to tamper with the expiry date or anything else in the token, the server will detect that the signature does not match, and will reject the token.

So yes, you'll be able to go to the guarded route, but as soon as you try to make an HTTP request, you'll get an error from the backend (or at least you **should** get one). The client-side guard is not really a security measure: the code of the component is available anyway in the downloaded bundle. It's an ergonomic measure: if the user can't access a route, he/she can be automatically redirected to the login page, for example.

Comment: My problem is I dont want user to view some pages. Say user is in page 1, fill in some personal details, he then navigate to page 2 and stay in page 2 too long or leave the application too long. When they are back, they can tamper to local expiry date so that they can navigate back to page 1 to view the personal details.

Comment: Where will page 1 get the personal details from? From the server, right? So it will send an HTTP request to the backend, with the JWT in the authorization header, right? And the server will check this token, and send back an error, right? So the page won't be able to get any peronal detail from the backend.

Comment: As far i know, if user either inputs or downloads information, it will be at least stored in memory, so that when we navigate back from page 2, we will dont need to send another request to server. Hence, when user is back to use the application, all data in memory might still there, and after tampering the token, they will be able to navigate back to page 1 and see all infor. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks JB

Comment: It stays on memory if you store it in memory and load the user details from memory. It doesn't if you don't do that, and instead get the data from the server.

Comment: Even we get data from server, it will be in memory so that when we navigate to/back from other pages, we dont need to call the same api again, do we?

Comment: Yes, you do. When you go to a route, the component of that route is instantiated, it typically loads the data it needs from the server, and its template displays this data. If you go to another route, that component is destroyed, with all the data it kept in its properties. If you go back, a new instance of the component is created again, and loads the data it needs to display, again. No, angular doesn't magically replace the http call made by the component with something magical that would get back the previously entered values and store them back in the new component.

Comment: That makes sense to me. I will try a simple example and observe the api calls to see how it works. Thanks for your help JB Nizet.